# Running vi within a bash script and executing vi commands to edit another file

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, editor, vi

So I've made a script which is collecting data from many different files:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir DATAPOOL"$1"

grep achi *out>runner
grep treat *out>>runner

cat runner | grep Primitive *gout | grep '=   '|awk '{print $1,$6}' > CellVolume"$1".txt 
cat runner | grep ' c ' *gout | grep 'Angstrom   '|awk '{print $1,$3}' > Cellc"$1".txt 
cat runner | grep 'Final energy ' *gout |awk '{print $1,$5}' > CellEnergy"$1".txt
```

etc etc

```
cat runner |awk '{print "~/xtlanal",$1," > ",$1}' >runner2
vi runner2
:1,$s/gout:/xtl/
:1,$s/gout:/dat/
:wq

source runner2

grep Summary *dat | grep 'CAT-O  ' |awk '{print $1,$6}' > AVE_NaO_"$1".txt

mv *txt DATAPOOL"$1"
```

So I end up with all the required text files when run without the vi part and so I know it all works. Furthermore when I run it with the vi commands, it just stops running at the vi command and then i can manually enter the 3 commands and I end up with the correct results. What I'm struggling with is I cant get vi to run the commands on its own so I can just execute the file multiple times within different directories and not have to manually enter commands time and time again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: It looks like you're trying to automate the use of vi.  Perhaps if you tell us what the `1,$s/gout:/xtl/` command does we can help you do it in a more straightforward way.

Comment: And what's wrong using `sed` instead of automating `vi`? like: `sed -i -e 's/gout:/xtl/' runner2` ?

Comment: yes there are multiple ways to edit/delete/create files other than vi which can be used in your script. why dont you try them?

Comment: The best way in which I've found to run VI within a script, is to use

    `vi runner2 -c ':1,$s/gout:/xtl/
     :1,$s/gout:/dat/
     :wq'`

This makes vi run the commands (which simply are substituting extensions on files). -c allows vim to pass executable commands. NB the apostrophes are needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For scripted editing tasks, you can use `ed` instead of vi:

```
ed runner2 <<'END'
1,$s/gout:/xtl/
1,$s/gout:/dat/
w
q
END
```

For global line-oriented search and replace, `sed` is a good choice:

```
sed -i 's/gout:/xtl/; s/gout:/dat/' runner2
```

Comment: +1, though I do not understand how it makes sense to replace `gout:` twice, since after the first replacement it will no longer be found by the second.  Anyway that seems to have come from the OP, so nothing against your answer.

Comment: My assumption is that it appears more than once on the line, the first will be replaced by "xtl", the second by "day" -- I didn't look that closely at the OP's code.

Comment: Ah yes of course, though why this all is happening I don't really know, but no matter, your answer is what I would have suggested (the sed way, specifically).  Simple.  :)  One note: `sed -i` requires an extra argument on some systems, to tell it the backup file suffix to use (even if it's just an empty one, e.g. on Mac OS X).

Answer (score 13):

something like this as a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
vi filename.txt -c ':g/^/m0' -c ':wq'
```

where `-c` execute a command. Here the command is to reverse the lines in a textfile. After done, `:wq` to save and exit. (man vi to get more about -c)

If you don't want to type `-c` twice, you can do it this way:

```
vi -c "g/^/m0 | wq" filename.txt
```

Comment: any idea how i can do -c 'ESC KEY PRESS' to exit insert mode?

Comment: hi, as far as I know the insert mode is off by default - you can change it in the .vimrc file `:startinsert`

Comment: You can use the ```\E``` to exit the insert mode.
More details available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37583965/11154428)

Answer (score 2):

#### Tested on VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Apr 10 2018 21:31:58)

The **vi -c "g/^/m0 | wq" filename.txt** may appear to work, but it does not actually!

Typing **vi -c "g/^/m0 | wq" filename.txt** will result in vi writing and quitting before any major changes are made to the file. (using the pipe in this situation will attempt to execute the wq line by line forcing it to quit before the intended operation)

In order to see a demonstration try typing it without the q and see how slow it works writing line by line:

```
vi -c "g/^/m0 | w" filename.txt
```

The more efficient way is using -c as B. Kocis states, or use +.

As B. Kocis stated:

```
#!/bin/bash
vi filename.txt -c ':g/^/m0' -c ':wq'
```

or

```
vi filename.txt +g/^/m0 +wq
```