# How can I use vi command in shell script?

Tags: shell, vi

I am using CentOS 6.7

I want open test.txt by vi and insert text "hihi"
then save and quit from vi.

```
#! /bin/bash

vi test.txt << 'END'
i
hihi
press ESC
w
q
END
```

The result like this

```
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...
Vim: preserving files...
Vim: Finished.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I suggest the workaround for your usecase is to use cat command in append mode

Comment: What's the point of using `vi` for what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to create or modify text files, ranging from `cat`, to `sed`, to `awk`, to `ed`.  I am going to assume, though, that you have a good reason for wanting to use `vi`.

Try this command:

```
echo $'ihihi\E:x\n' | vi test.txt
```

In operation, this looks like:

```
$ echo $'ihihi\E:x\n' | vi test.txt
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
$ cat test.txt
hihi
```

I found this approach to be fragile: if `vi` experiences an error condition, no message will be seen.

#### How it works

We need to get `vi` to see an escape character.  There are many ways to do that.  I chose to use bash's `$'...'` strings as it allows escape to be entered as a simple two character string: `\E`.  The steps that we use are:

1. `i` introduces *insert* mode.
2. The four characters `hihi` are entered into the buffer.
3. Escape, `\E`, exits *insert* mode.
4. `:x\n` exits with save.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use vi for something this simple. You can use `echo`. For example:

```
echo "hihi" > test.txt
```

If you are really trying to do something more complex, post some more details.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 2):

Calling vim from bash:

```
vim test.txt +$'i\nhihi' +w +q
```

You may also want to check out "ed".  That is an editor with kind of similar commands to vi, but it is actually designed to be called from scripts.

Comment: note, the `i` is not to enter Insert mode. It is actually doing a cmd-line command `:i` or `:insert`. See http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#%3Ainsert

Answer (score 1):

`vi` is historicaly the *visual* mode of an old editor `ex`, an extended version of the good old `ed`. You can always revert to the old line mode by using `ex` or `vi -e`.

That way, it just read from standard input, so it can easily be used in bash scripts.

Here it would be

```
ex test.txt << END
i
hihi
.
wq
END
```

(the dot is used to get out of the input mode in line mode, like in `ed`)

Answer (score 0):

Using vi command from the shell works this way:

```
vi -c "set fileformat=unix | wq" filename.txt
```

However, this will not work for such commands like g.

You will need to use two -c arguments for this to work such as:

```
vi -c g/^/m0 -c wq filename.txt
```

or

```
vi filename.txt -c g/^/m0 -c wq
```

Happy Coding!

---

**P.S.
In the case where you are using:**

```
vi test.txt +$'i\nhihi' +wq
```

This will insert before the current line in memory!

For example if you previously inserted "hihi" before line 20 with this command:

```
vi test.txt +20$'i\nhihi' +wq     (insert hihi before line 20)

vi test.txt +20$'a\nhihi' +wq     (insert hihi after line 20)
```

Then typing with no number specified will use the last number in memory.

```
vi test.txt +$'i\nhihi' +wq     (This command will now insert before line 20)

vi test.txt +$'a\nhihi' +wq     (This command will now insert after line 20)
```

**You will have to reset the line number in memory by specifying a new number:**

```
vi test.txt +0$'i\nhihi' +wq          (add hihi before line 0 to very top)
vi test.txt +0$'a\nhihi' +wq          (add hihi after line 0 to very top)
vi test.txt +1$'i\nhihi' +wq          (add hihi before line 1 to very top)
vi test.txt +1$'a\nhihi' +wq          (add hihi after line 1 as line 2)
```

---

### If the last line number in test.txt is not known the lines can be counted using wc.

(adding hihi before last line)

```
vi test.txt +$(wc -l < test.txt)$'i\nhihi' +wq
```

or

(adding hihi after last line)

```
vi test.txt +$(wc -l < test.txt)$'a\nhihi' +wq
```

---